# Chef: can a node be shared across multiple organizations?

Tags: chef-infra

Can a node (server) be shared across more than one organization? I'm assuming no. I'm asking because we bootstrapped multiple servers to our Chef org so we can deploy and run our cookbooks/recipes on them. However, recently another team at our company bootstrapped these same nodes to their own Chef org so they can run their own cookbooks on these servers. This broke us! Now we are unable to run our cookbooks on these nodes.

What is the best way to fix this? Do we need the other team to delete the nodes/clients from their Chef org? Is there anything else we can do?

Comment: Short answer nothing: a node belong to one org only. you may tweak the config file used and key used but that's likely you'll get a conflict between teams on one file someday (for example)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I actually did swap out the client.rb and client.pem on one of the nodes, which seemed to have helped, but like you implied this is just temporary. We'll have to work out a better solution with the other team.

Comment: FWIW my position is that multiple organization is likely to become a pain very quickly if there's no well defined workflow around them to tell which node belong to which organization.

Comment: Agreed. Not sure if this is an actual design flaw in Chef. Might be a good idea to allow multiple teams at a company to have their own separate Chef orgs where they can manage their own nodes and custom cookbooks that they can use across shared servers. Otherwise, you'd have a single monolithic org with a large number of nodes and cookbooks, etc. that could become unwieldy to manage. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Please copy this down to an answer

Comment: added a word about your comment for multiple org on same server also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer nothing: a node belong to one org only.
You may tweak the config file used and key used but that's likely you'll get a conflict between teams on one file someday (for example)

FWIW my position is that multiple organization is likely to become a pain very quickly if there's no well defined workflow around them to tell which node belong to which organization.

To answer the comment under the question:

> Not sure if this is an actual design flaw in Chef. Might be a good
>   idea to allow multiple teams at a company to have their own separate
>   Chef orgs where they can manage their own nodes and custom cookbooks
>   that they can use across shared servers.

It is not a flaw of Chef design and allowing this would result on crazy things, let's say:

- Team A has specific needs for X11 forwarding through ssh and makes it's cookbook to configure sshd this way
- Team B has specific need to enforce mfa use on ssh, and part of hardening disallow X11 forwarding.

Share the server, then each chef run on org A or org B will reconfigure SSH, never being compliant for both team.

Comment: What if Team A does what you say, but Team B has a specific need that has absolutely nothing to do with Team A. For example, copy code and install an application. There is literally no overlap between the two teams. That's the scenario we are faced with right now.

Comment: You'll have an overlap one day. Let's say on tomcat ENV variables, each team responsible of his cookbook is absolutely ok and a chef server can absolutely cope with a high amount of cookbooks.

Comment: Agreed. I think this basically comes down to proper Chef planning and management within a company.

Comment: As you won't join a server to two domains or realm,  you'll make a trust between domains at best but the server will always belong to only one domain. It's more a general planning in the company than a chef only problem. Devops ideas are there to smooth this kind of planning :)

Comment: I don't think think this situation is as clear cut as some people seem to believe.
For instance, there's always a need to have common security settings across teams/orgs within a company but still have separate organizations for each team because they work on different products within that company.

Comment: @user would you join to two ad domains to apply two set of gpo or just ensure each domain apply the company wide policy?